# browser-sync cannot proxy https-websites

Tags: https, browser-sync

I use [browser-sync](https://www.browsersync.io/) 2.11.1 with OS X Chrome 48.0.2564.97 (64-bit)

When I use it as a proxy for http-website:

`browser-sync start --proxy http://example.com`

it works great and I can point multiple browsers to localhost:3000 so that actions done in one of them are replicated in others.

However when I use it for https-website:

`browser-sync start --proxy https://twitter.com`

it doesn't work. When I point browsers to localhost:3000 they do not show up in "Current Connections" of browser-sync UI and also the actions are not replicated between them.

Maybe it has something to do with my browser complaining about https:
[image: https-error]

Is there a bug in browser-sync or am I missing something?

Comment: Reported the issue: https://github.com/BrowserSync/browser-sync/issues/992

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Apparently `https://twitter.com` is just a bad example. When I try `https://about.gitlab.com/` the synchronization between my browsers does work:

```
browser-sync start --proxy https://about.gitlab.com/ --logLevel debug
```

[According](https://github.com/BrowserSync/browser-sync/issues/992#issuecomment-185927096) to the maintainer of browser-sync:

> any large site like twitter has multiple techniques in place to
>   prevent proxing like this - and rightly so.
>
> Browsersync is a development tool to be used on local addresses that
>   you're working on - in those cases it will work fine with HTTPS -
>   you'll just have to click accept on the warning about self-signed
>   certs :)

Answer (score 3):

You might need to set **https** to **true**

```
browserSync({
    proxy: "http://example.com/",
    https: true
});
```

if that doesn't work try to append the https url to browserSync

```
browserSync.init({
    socket: {
              domain: "https://example.com" //with port if any => localhost:3000
            },
    proxy: 'http://example.com'
});
```

Comment: can you provide more context? Should I insert the snippet into some configuration file? I use browser-sync as a standalone command line utility

Comment: If I launch it via `browser-sync start --proxy https://twitter.com/ --https` I still see the same warning

Comment: There's no error in the console. But see my answer: most likely it's because twitter is just a bad example

Answer (score 3):

### How to get secure gray lock icon in Chrome when using BrowserSync and xip.io and Wamp

First, generate .key and .crt files for localhost by running [this](https://letsencrypt.org/docs/certificates-for-localhost/) in WSL or whatever you use for Bash:

```
cd /mnt/c/wamp64/certs/
openssl req -x509 -out localhost.crt -keyout localhost.key \
  -newkey rsa:2048 -nodes -sha256 \
  -subj '/CN=localhost' -extensions EXT -config <( \
   printf "[dn]\nCN=localhost\n[req]\ndistinguished_name = dn\n[EXT]\nsubjectAltName=DNS:localhost\nkeyUsage=digitalSignature\nextendedKeyUsage=serverAuth")
```

Use PowerShell to tell Chome to trust that .crt file:

```
PS C:\wamp64\certs> certutil -addstore -enterprise -f "Root" .\localhost.crt
```

Completely exit Chrome (not just some tabs) by clicking ⋮ > Exit.

My BrowserSync [options](https://browsersync.io/docs/options/):

```
{
    proxy: {
        target: "https://myapp.192.168.1.113.xip.io" // Proxy an EXISTING vhost. Browsersync will wrap your vhost with a proxy URL to view your site.
    },
    host: "localhost", //the crt must have been created to match this (probably)
    https: {            //https://browsersync.io/docs/options/#option-https        
        key: "C:\\wamp64\\certs\\localhost.key", 
        cert: "C:\\wamp64\\certs\\localhost.crt"
    },
    port: 3000
}
```

Now https://localhost:3000/ works with a gray lock icon in the top left, as it should.

Comment: I can't believe this hasn't gotten any upvotes. Worked almost perfectly for me. The only thing is, the site no longer auto refreshes upon rebuilding the CSS files. Refresh on changes to `index.html` works fine. Any thoughts?

Comment: @Karl I'm not sure. Whatever this project was, I haven't touched it in a long time. I'll be curious to hear a follow-up from you though when you figure it out. Thanks!

Comment: the cause of my problem turned out to be stupidity. Mine. I had the watch option set to watch only for changes. At some point, I had added a cleanup step to the build to delete the destination folder, which means the CSS file was being created, not changed. I removed the cleanup and all is good.

Comment: @Karl Thanks for the update! Glad it all worked out.